# Can I improve performance when I use subquery to reduce some results before inner join statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Which one is the most efficiency for mysql query between sql1 and sql1?

sql1 is the following:

```
select count(t1.id) as amount, sum(t1.charge_price) as charge_price,
       t2.city_id, t2.pile_type
from
    (
    select id, charge_price, pile_id from t_order
    where date(order_time) = '2015-11-12'
    ) t1,
    t_charging_pile t2
where t1.pile_id = t2.id
  and order_state in (5, 7) group by t2.pile_type,t2.city_id
```

sql2 is the following:

```
select count(t1.id) as amount, sum(t1.charge_price) as charge_price,
       t2.city_id, t2.pile_type
from t_order t1,
     t_charging_pile t2
where t1.pile_id = t2.id
  and date(order_time) = '2015-11-12'
  and order_state in (5, 7) group by t2.pile_type,t2.city_id
```

If they all have lower performance, how can I optimize these queries to reach my goals.

Comment: There is simply not enough information to answer your question. Pls attach the create table statements for all affected tables and the explain outputs for both queries. Also, pls describe what you try to achive with these queries.

Comment: Moreover, you can time both queries on your database. Whichever runs faster is probably the better solution out of the 2.

Comment: Both queries are invalid, at least ANSI SQL-wise. (Mix of aggregate functions and plain columns, but no GROUP BY.)

Comment: ps. Both two sql have the group clause:group by t2.pile_type,t2.city_id.As careless,i omited.